# Text inside Circular Progress of Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I was wondering...does anyone know if it's possible to add customized text on the inside of the a Material UI Circular Progress element?  If so, what is the best way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the google images for the circular progress meter provided by material ui it appears one can change the inner text.

Answer (score 4):

You can make the text absolute and place it on top of Progress bar.

```
<div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
    <span style={{position: 'absolute', top: '10px', left: '2px'}}>100%</span>
    <CircularProgress />
</div>
```

`top` and `left` values you can set as per you.

Answer (score 3):

Material-UI is based on the Material Design spec by Google.
The [spec for "Progress Activity"](https://material.io/guidelines/components/progress-activity.html#progress-activity-types-of-indicators) doesn't have text inside any of the circular elements. MUI is only going to officially support the material design spec.

If you take a look at [the code for `CircularProgress`](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/CircularProgress/CircularProgress.js), then you can see that it is rendering a SVG element. (Also visible in dev tools in your browser.)

I suggest you fork MUI and fiddle with the Circular Progress element until you get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Add <Box/> with `display: flex`, `justifyContent: center` and `alignItems: center`. Also Add `position: absolute` to <Typography/>

```
<Box display='flex' justifyContent='center' alignItems='center'>
    <CircularProgress/>
    <Typography position='absolute'>{99}%</Typography>
</Box>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Like Mike pointed out, In Mui there is no built in support for adding text inside progressbar. Using css absolute property is an option ,but can have potential responsiveness issues. I suggest to use [React-circular-progressbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-circular-progressbar) as an alternative. It is responsive, but make sure you use it within some other parent element like Box/Paper or anything else of required size.